# How do you breed animals?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft, I know you can breed animals. In fact, in recent updates it's required for the player who just can't start their mornings without bacon and eggs!

I've tried pulling two pigs together in a single pen, but all they do is snort at me. And the chickens? Well, there's plenty of eggs, but no hatching.

How do I get them to make more bacon and eggs?

Comment: How is babby formed?

Comment: How woman get pragenant.

Comment: Great question!

Comment: The edited title makes the question much less interesting. Change it back.

Comment: Oh, *now* those comments make much more sense. Thanks @PeterOlson. :P

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Feed both animals their specific food at same time, while they are beside each other. That will make them have hearts above their heads and breed with each other.

- Sheep: wheat
- Cows: wheat
- Pigs: carrots or potatoes
- Chickens: seeds, any type (wheat, pumpkin, melon, or even Nether wart)
- Horses: Golden Apple or Golden Carrot
- Tame wolves: bones (to tame). Rotten flesh and any form of meat, cooked or raw
- Tame cats/ocelot: raw fish  (sneak, holding fish so it walks up to you, then tame)
- Turtles: seagrass (can be obtained with shears)
- Dolphins: raw cod
- Polar bears: fish (any kind)
- Pandas: bamboo
- Parrots: seeds

Comment: Usually in humans, the wheat must be fermented first...

Comment: And, depending on attractiveness, distilled a few times.

Answer (score 10):

Take a look at [Breeding on the Minecraft Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Breeding).

Basically, you must feed them both one wheat.  Then they would go towards each other and hopfully have a baby.

Here is actually a video of the 'action':

The only thing not shown in this video is the fact that the new 'babies' are actually a baby form of the animal, they are smaller and much cuter :)

Comment: "Go towards each other." Is that what the kids are calling it nowadays? Sounds so sterile and un-romantic. :(

Comment: *flags* This is nsfw.

Answer (score 2):

Pigs, Sheep, Cows and Chickens can all be "breed" by feeding them wheat.  (To feed an animal wheat, carry wheat, and right click the animal.)  Once an animal "eats" the wheat, it gets hearts above it.  Once two animals get close to each other with hearts above them, they create a tiny animal.  Each animal can reproduce once per minecraft day (or so.)

Chickens can reproduce in another way.  You can take an egg, and throw it on the ground.  About 1 in 8 times, a chick will hatch from the egg.  This is the only way to get a passive mob from the normal world, to the nether or the end.

Answer (score 0):

To make pet cats, you take two ocelots and feed them fish (any type) at the same time, try it a couple more times then you get a cat! For a dog you take one  wolf and feed him a bone a couple times then you get a dog withe a collar!

WARNING: they both transport and sometimes follow you. To make them sit, use the button you use to put a block down.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score -2):

To breed animals and humans there is always an ingredient that you need.

1. Cows - wheat
2. Sheep - wheat
3. chickens - seeds
4. pigs - carrots
5. horses/mules/donkeys - wheat, apples, golden apples, golden carrots
6. Taming wolves to dogs - bones to tame and raw meat to mate
7. Taming ocelots to cats - fish
8. Humans - building a 3x3 structure then adding a door (they will not breed without a door)

Cows, sheep and pigs can breed every minecraft day. Chickens can breed twice every minecraft day.

Horses, dogs and cats can breed every other minecraft day.

Humans have a 40% chance to breed with every door you place on your structure.

Comment: This doesn't add anything that the other existing answers have not covered.

Comment: @Rory None of the answers include anything about humans

Comment: @PeterV. I mean he means villagers when he says humans...